# What to subclass for clickedRow (NSTableView)

Tags: cocoa, subclass, nstableview

Which method should I subclass to change the drawing when a row is right-mouse clicked? (I want to change it in selecting the row).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you want [the `highlightSelectionInClipRect:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/highlightSelectionInClipRect:).

If you're looking to make a source list (like in iTunes, Mail, and the Finder), you should use [the `setSelectionHighlightStyle:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setSelectionHighlightStyle:) (or set that property in IB) instead.

Comment: And what if I right-click on it? I actually meant to change the blue ring thing that you see when you right-click on it in a selected highlight.. http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/7310/picture5nn.png

Answer (score 2):

Implement the delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`

Comment: Hmm, maybe I explained my problem not good enough. I mean when you right-click on it. Then you get this blue focus thing (like when you drop a file on an NSTableView) and as far as I can tell it's not the focusring from the NSView http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/7310/picture5nn.png
(got this from the DragNDropOutlineView example from Apple)